# TextMeshProUGUI.Text NullReferenceException in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI countText;
    private int count;

    void Start()
    {
        count = 0;
        SetCountText();
    }

    void SetCountText()
    {
        countText.text = $"Score: {count}";
    }

}
```

Accessing `countText` triggers NullReferenceException. None of the solutions offered online work. What is even more suspicious is the fact code is taken from official unity tutorial. I suppose someone made a mistake.

Some additional info:
[how it looks like in unity ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scjqj.png)
[CountText settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwRkD.png)

Everything seems to be in order.

Comment: You did not assign the reference most likely.  You didnt show us NewBehaviourScript on an object, but I guarantee that is where the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @No this does not answer my question, I know what NullReferenceException is. And yes reference was not set, most of tutorials skip this step. If you post it as full answer I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Debug](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Debug.html) class provided by unity is a helpful tool, and should be used extensively during your games development.

```
Debug.Log($"My object is {myObject}");
```

Some references are set during design time using the `Inspector` window.
These references must be set before entering play mode, otherwise they will be `null`.  You can set the reference by dragging an object of that type onto the object field in the inspector.

A null reference will happen when you attempt to access a member of a null object.

```
public class DisplayPlayerName : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI uiName;
    public GameObject player;

    void Start()
    {
        uiName.text = player.name; // <- whoops! NullReferenceException
    }
}
```

In the example above, if either `uiName` or `player` are not set in the inspector, a null reference exception will be thrown.  This is because we are accessing a member of each of those objects.  We want to set the `text` property of uiName to the `name` property of player.

> But how do we know which one game object is causing the problem?  I have a *million* gameobjects and don't want to check them all!

**Tricks to help narrow your search**

Debug the name of the object that threw the exception.

```
if (player == null ||
    uiName == null) // <- do some null checking
{
    Debug.Log($"{name} has null player or ui"); // <- log the gameobjects name
    return; // <- exit the function
}

// This won't throw the exception anymore because we exit the function when null is detected
//
uiName.text = player.name;
```

Logging the objects name is most helpful when we name every object (or at least the most important ones) in a meaningful way.

You can filter the objects in your scene to those that have a specific component on it.  Using the search bar in the `Hierarchy` window, type `t:` followed by the name of your component eg. `t:DisplayPlayerName`.  This will show only the objects that have that component attached.

Hopefully this provides you with some new tools for debugging in unity.